# How do you enable ntlm v3 on windows server 2008 on IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntlm

My boss wants me to enable NTLM v3 on IIS on my Windows 2008 server instance.

How do I do that? Googling it is very non-conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do NTLM stuff all day and I can assure you,there is is no such thing as NTLMv3. Depending on your boss, you can mock her/him, or ask for more details and see what happens.  Ask why. :-P

Maybe he/she meant SMBv3.  I am amazed how often they are confused.  In the context of IIS this is kid of nonsensical. That is, it is on by default and all servers should have SMBv1 disabled, not just IIS.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server